# How to fire dragend event of a marker in google maps v3?

Tags: events, google-maps, marker

I want to fire dragend event of a marker in another event say click event on the map. how can I do that?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(pt){
   posSelectMarker.setPosition(pt.latLng);
   //Here I want to fire dragend event.
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`event.trigger`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapsEventListener);

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markerObject, 'dragend', args);
```

Comment: Why? The event callback needs to _know_ which marker!

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit more complete:

```
theListener = google.maps.event.addListener(posSelectMarker,'dragend',function(event){
    console.log(event.latLng);
});
```

Note that you can get at the object with the event param

Comment: this is not the answer. you add listener instead of execute it

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener
```

instead of:

```
google.maps.event.trigger
```

Quick example:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker_var_name, 'dragend', function(){
    alert('drag ended')
});
```

Comment: triggering means firing the event manually. addListener is used for listening on an event.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the marker object, you could call `addListener` directly to add a `dragend` event.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    ...
)};

marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
    // do something
});
```